# Rounding w/ SUMIF (HELP)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently using the following formula to populate the sum of specific data within a sheet:

=SUM(SUMIF(D:D,{"H0032","H0031"},F:F))

However, I am in search of an addition to this formula. I have a duration column(F) in which I have minutes from 1-250. I need this formula to round down by multiples of 15. So if a cell in column F was 44, I would want the formula to convert it to 30 before summing "H0032" & "H0031". If a cell in column F was 46, I would want the formula to convert it to 45 before summing.

Please let me know if you are aware of a formula that allows me to do all of these things.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use this array formula

```
=SUM(IF(((D1:D100="H0032")+(D1:D100="H0031"))>0,INT(F1:F100/15)*15))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Or this SUMPRODUCT() that can be entered normally:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((D1:D100=90791)+(D1:D100=99343))>0)*INT(F1:F100/15)*15)
```

Also note that the references are no longer full column and should be set to the extents of the data set to avoid unnecessary calculations.